# Not getting appropriate php string result from mysql_query()

Tags: php, mysql

I'm looking to label a string based on database results. I have the following code:

```
$loc1 = "A";
$query  = "SELECT loc FROM User where nick='".$users[$j]."'";
    $loc = mysql_query($query);
    if($loc == 1)
        $loc1 = "A";
    if($loc== 2)
        $loc1 = "B";
```

The loc1 location is always "A". I've confirmed that the query works in MySQL and I'm having a difficult time understanding why this simple case is not working. I would appreciate your help!

Comment: `$loc` is mysql resource and not mysql data

Comment: Check out the usage examples in the [mysql_query() docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-query.php).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The function `mysql_query` does not return the value of the column fetched, instead it returns a MySQL resource which you use to extract the column value returned by the query.

Change:

```
$loc = mysql_query($query);
```

to:

```
$result = mysql_query($query);
if (!$result) {
    die('Invalid query: ' . mysql_error());
}
if ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $loc = $row["loc"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are storing mysql_query() return value in $loc which is a resource.

For SELECT, SHOW, DESCRIBE, EXPLAIN and other statements returning resultset, mysql_query() returns a resource on success, or FALSE on error.

So, $loc is not 1 or neither equals to 2.

You need to use mysql_fetch_array / mysql_fetch_object, etc to manipulate the resource.

Answer (score 1):

You must fetch the recordset with, in example [mysql_fetch_row](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-row.php)

Example #1 Fetching one row with mysql_fetch_row()

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT id,email FROM people WHERE id = '42'");
if (!$result) {
    echo 'Could not run query: ' . mysql_error();
    exit;
}
$row = mysql_fetch_row($result);

echo $row[0]; // 42
echo $row[1]; // the email value
?>
```

But, be careful with SQL injection attacks!

http://es.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php